# How to implement surveys using SDL Tridion

Tags: 2013, publishing, external-integrations

How to implement a Marketing Survey using SDL Tridion.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct answer would be: "any way you like".

But to give you a hint in the right direction, for a survey you need forms, and something handling their responses. Both can be found in for instance [Wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/).

And there just happens to be a nice [ECL provider](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/wufoo_ecl_provider.aspx) for that, available for free on [SDL Tridion World](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/wufoo_ecl_provider.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange site!

You have probably already found from your initial investigation that Tridion does not provide survey/forms functionality 'out of the box' (unless you are/have one of the few customers using Tridion WebForms).

As Bart suggests, you will need some kind of 'forms' functionality to implement this.

You could write your own survey forms in .NET, JSP, or similar, and then process the survey in your application code. However, as Bart says, I would recommend that you don't try to re-invent the wheel, and instead, integrate a 3rd party survey tool (Wufoo, Survey Monkey, etc.) into your published website.

If you are experiencing any specific **Tridion** problems when you come to implement this, then you can raise your questions, giving as much detail as possible, here.